# spring-integration-kafka : Multi message(s) - partition - consumer relationship

Tags: spring, spring-integration, apache-kafka

Requirement:

Let say I am receiving message from 3 organisation and want to process them separately/orderly by separate consumers.

m-many messages from a given organisation
example
m1: many messages from oragnisation 1

p-partition
c-consumer

for a given topic and consumer group.

```
m1  P1  c1
m2  P2  c2
m3  P3  c3
```

Now ,later at runtime new organisation join.SO,it should be new entry i.e new partition/new consumer

```
m1  P1  c1
m2  P2  c2
m3  P3  c3

m4  p4  c4
```

also,if for any reason any consumer dies of then the partion should not get distributed among the rest of the consumer but shld get replaced with new consumer in place of the recently lost one.Idea is to maintain 1 to 1 relation ship among the m-->p-->c,so as to keep track of what is coming from which organisation.

example: if c3 dies of,then it shld be replaced with c5 immediatetly w/o loosing data and start consuming from where c3 left and so on.

I am using spring-integration-kafka 1.2.1.RELEASE

is it possible?looking for best possible solution.
Would be great, if get the code snippet/sample for producer and consumer for the version(1.2.1) mention above.
Many thanks.

Comment: Also is there any documentation/material available  covering the details of  usage for the spring-integration-kafka 1.2.1.RELEASE understanding.idea is to get better understanding of this version for efficient usage.

Comment: still no solution ?